# grub error on installing ubuntu on dual boot with windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have tried to **install Ubuntu** latest version on my computer hp pavilion dv6 using `rufus` i have copied Ubuntu iso image on my flash drive and restart my pc , on bootloader option i chose my flash to boot first , my bios is **legacy** version not uEFI
i keep getting ***welcome to grub!*** and ubuntu installation is not loading

what can i do ?
how can i install a linux with my windows so whenever needed try to restart and chose linux

ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu 23.04 LTS which is the *latest* version is available using `subiquity` installer (Ubuntu 23.04 Server), or `ubuntu-desktop-installer` (Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop primary ISO) or `ubiquity` (Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop *legacy* ISO) but you've not said which you actually used. If you used an older version of `rufus`, or inappropriate options you can have failure to write the grub boot details, but you gave no specifics there either.

Comment: Thank u  so much for reply , this is the version that i haved downloaded ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64 , if you please give me a link for downloading a version to install on my laptop with dual boot , give me a link that i can learn from it to install thank u

Comment: You have download Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop (the default or *primary* ISO which uses the `ubuntu-desktop-installer`). At download there is an option to download the *legacy* ISO which uses the alternate `ubiquity` installer which performs better on some hardware; you could try it, or wait for others to offer suggestions. I have little experience with `rufus` (*sorry I don't use it; am just aware of potential problems if not used properly as it allows reformatting of ISOs that can prevent correct installs*) BUT I performed QA-tests of Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop on BIOS or non-uEFI hardware without issue